# Click and Get ArrayValue

Tags: javascript

I want display the First value in Array when I click, click again, show the 2nd Value in Array (increase by one...)

```js
 const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    const content = document.querySelector('.content');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click',getArray);
    
    function getArray(event){
       const items = [10,20,30,40,50];
        

    }
```

```html
<button class="btn">Array Index</button>
<div class="content">
    
    </div>
```

Comment: first things first: your code is javascript, not Java

Comment: what problem do you have with this? just keep a counter, and use said counter as index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [10,20,30,40,50];
var x = "";
var i = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
if( i < items .length) {
x += items [i++] + "<br>";
}
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = x;
}

<p id="text"></p>
<button id="btn">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach, using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const gen = getNextNumber();
    
btn.addEventListener('click',getArray);
    
function getArray(event){
   content.innerText = gen.next().value;
}
    
function *getNextNumber() {
    const items = [10,20,30,40,50];
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        yield items[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Array Index</button>
<div class="content">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this fits your needs:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
let counter = 0; // Counter to access the index

btn.addEventListener('click', getArray);

function getArray() { // Removed 'event' here -> not necessary
  const items = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

  if (counter < items.length) { // Prevent getting "undefined"
    content.innerText = items[counter]; // Change the content of your div
    counter++; // Increase counter to get the next index
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Array Index</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

I added my changes and additions to your code as comments

Comment: @MohamedIrshath Glad to help :).

Comment: So... why exaclty got my answer downvoted right now without an explenation why, dear downvoter?